# VBA using both date & time columns to find latest time

Tags: excel, vba

Doing VBA program...have very long list of dates (11/23/2016, etc) in column G, and times h:m:s ( 23:15:27 ) in another column K

Need VBA method to find the earliest and latest date-times, probably using min and max function..these functions seem to work on either column just fine....but how to do so on two columns. Note a later *appearing * time (say 09:23:11 vs 03:25:11) might be the actual earlier real datetime if it occurs on an earlier date.

I DO NOT want to generate any additional column, as these are all highly specified as to the displayed arrangement, just ant to use the info already present

tried min and max over the column range of cells...they work fine on either column, but need the min of the COMBINED column information

Comment: `=MAX(G:G+K:K)`.

Comment: sorry but =MAX(G:G+K:K) just gives 0:00:0, tried  6/19/89  11:23:44
3/13/13  2:19:27
11/23/10  4:08:44
5/5/98  16:27:33
4/27/78  7:29:33

Answer (score 0):

For the maximum, a simple [array formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) (validation using `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`) will do:

```
=MAX(G:G+K:K)
```

For the minimum, all the cells under the range you use (all the way down to the bottom of the worksheet) are blanks that must be ignored. Again to be validated as an array formula:

```
=MIN(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(G:G)), G:G+K:K))
```

However, if your columns have a text header, you need to adapt the formula to ignore non number values (behind the scene, dates and times are number in Excel); blanks are not numbers:

```
=MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(G:G), G:G+K:K))
=MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(G:G), G:G+K:K))
```

Better yet, there are ways to stop formulas from evaluating on entire columns, meaning you can simplify the formulas to ignore the header and the bottom of the worksheet.

Better yet, if you can format your range as a table (see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-table-in-excel-bf0ce08b-d012-42ec-8ecf-a2259c9faf3f) and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e)), and assuming your table is named `Table1` and the columns `Date column` and `Time column`:

```
=MAX(Table1[Date column]+Table2[Time column])
=MIN(Table1[Date column]+Table2[Time column])
```

Comment: =MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(G:G), G:G+K:K))  DOES NOT WORK   colum G has 7/10/2022
3/4/2019
4/5/2020
11/20/2019
3/4/2019
column k has12:14:23
11:22:35
9:21:24
2:27:33
12:33:45
it should show 3/4/2019  at 11:22:35 as the min, but shows zero

Comment: It does work, I suspect you are not following the instructions I left exactly. Also, why do you expect the `MAX` to return the the first date? That is what `MIN` does, not `MAX`.

Comment: If found the issue , I just copied/pasted your solution into the cell...it will not work like that  ...you needed to include leading and ending curly  braces:  {=MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(G:G), G:G+K:K)) }  by using ctrl+shift+enter    ...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: an example in office2007]

Don't forget to press Shift+Ctrl+Enter on formulas. For some reason the MAX/MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(G:G);H:H+G:G)) works but the: MAX/MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(G:G);G:G+H:H)) doesn't work. That is, the hours of the days must precede the summation

Comment: Thanks a lot!! However, I am programming in VBA ---are the exact same commands used there? The spreadsheet of values is sheet1. I will display the result in a msgbox and also use it for some other things in VBA logic

Comment: Do you mean that you want to take the Min and Max with VBA? Why? Just copy the value of Cells e.g. F2 and F3 of my example in VBA code and use it...

Comment: I tried putting msgbox(cstr(MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(G:G);H:H+G:G)) )) in VBA, but I just get a bunch of errors.  HOW DO YOU DO THIS IN VBA??? I need to look at the sheet: column of dates and their corresponding column of times and find the min date-time so I can program different logic depending on the result.

Comment: I don't know any way to execute the array formula from VBA. It is simplest to do: Dim asum as Variant: asum = Workbooks("sheet1").Range("MIN_CELL").Value  where MIN_CELL in my example is the cell F3. After use the variable asum in msgbox or anywhere...

Comment: Can VBA use an array formula?  Or maybe an entirely different  method?  Seems like there would be a VBA time function to look at the spreadsheet and find the earliest  date/time  (date and time are in separate columns), there will be thousands of rows of these timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code on this data:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Public minDate As Long
Public maxDate As Long

Sub FindMinMax()
Dim i As Long
Dim minDateTime As Double
Dim maxDateTime As Double
Dim tempDateTime As Double

minDateTime = #12/31/9999# - 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 + 1
maxDateTime = 0

    For i = 2 To Range("A1:B20").Rows.Count
        tempDateTime = Range("A1:B20")(i, 1) + Range("A1:B20")(i, 2)
        If minDateTime > tempDateTime Then minDateTime = tempDateTime
        If maxDateTime < tempDateTime Then maxDateTime = tempDateTime
    Next i
    
    Range("F1") = minDateTime
    Range("F2") = maxDateTime

End Sub 'FindMinMax
```