# Need to VBA combine columns during search

Tags: excel, vba, date, time

Doing VBA program...have very long list (hundred thousand+)of timestamps: date (11/23/2016, etc) in column G, and times h:m:s ( 23:15:27 ) in another column K

Need VBA method to find the earliest and latest timestamp (any duplication returns only 1 result for early/late), THIS MUST BE VBA CODE, and not change or delete any columns that are presented, as these are all highly specified as to the displayed arrangement, just want to use the info already present.  These two results are needed to drive some decision logic and other things happening in VBA.

So when the VBA finds the newest/oldest timestamp it must be using BOTH the date and time columns together (since you can have different times on the same date).  These timestamps are not necessarily in order (and must not be reordered).

I tried some VBA date functions,  but have no luck in somehow working both columns.

Comment: Please post what you already tried.

Comment: If the dates aren’t ordered and must be reordered why can’t you use Excel’s sort feature? Then, the earliest and latest time stamp are at rows 1 and n respectively.

Comment: I CAN NOT sort the data, the spreadsheet display must NOT be touched.  So how can it be done in VBA? This result is needed in VBA to do other things.   I was trying to figure out how to do a cellarray in VBA , but always just got errors.

Comment: You asked the same question twice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75710374/vba-using-both-date-time-columns-to-find-latest-time/

Answer (score 0):

Another way, if you don't mind to have helper a column and assume that column XFA is free so it will be used as the helper column ....

```
Sub test()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cnt As Integer: Dim mx As Date: Dim mn As Date

Set sh = ActiveSheet 'change if needed

With sh
    cnt = .Range("G2", Range("G2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
End With

With sh.Range("XFA2").Resize(cnt, 1)
    .Value = "=G2+K2"
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss"
    .Value = .Value
    mx = Application.Max(.Cells)
    mn = Application.Min(.Cells)
    MsgBox "Earliest Date " & mn & " in row " & .Cells.Find(CStr(mn)).Row
    MsgBox "Latest Date " & mx & " in row " & .Cells.Find(CStr(mx)).Row
    .Clear
End With

End Sub
```

The code assumes that starting from row 2 - the dates are in column G and the timestamps are in column K. Also the code assumes that nothing in column XFA and column XFA won't be used for processing something.

It create cnt variable to count how many rows of data in column G, then fill column XFA with formula `=g2+k2`.

Then get the max and min value in column XFA as mx and mn variable
Then show the msgbox of the max value and it's row. 
Then show the msgbox of the min value and it's row.

---

If you insist that you don't want to add a helper column ....

```
Sub test2()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim mnD As Date: Dim mxD As Date
Dim mnT As Date: Dim mxT As Date
Dim rgMnD As Range: Dim rgMxD As Range

Set sh = ActiveSheet 'change if needed

With sh.Range("G2", sh.Range("G2").End(xlDown))
    mnD = Application.Min(.Cells)
    mxD = Application.Max(.Cells)
    
    .Replace mnD, True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
    Set rgMnD = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical).Offset(0, 4)
    .Replace True, mnD, xlWhole, , False, , False, False

    .Replace mxD, True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
    Set rgMxD = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical).Offset(0, 4)
    .Replace True, mxD, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
End With

mnT = Application.Min(rgMnD)
mxT = Application.Max(rgMxD)
MsgBox "Earliest Date " & mnD & " " & mnT
MsgBox "Latest Date " & mxD & " " & mxT

End Sub
```

mnD and mxD is the min and max value in Date column (column G).

then it create rgMnD as the range offset (0,4) from column G which contains the mnD, and create rgMxD as the range offset (0,4) from column G which contains the mxD.

mnT and mxT is the min and max value in rgMnD and rgMxD.

Comment: WOW!! Thanks a lot!!  This looks very good.   Never thought/heard of a helper column (I will have to delete it afterwards).  I like that avoids a for loop, since there can be several hundred thousand rows  (not sure about speed effects).

Comment: you don't have to delete the helper column, because in the code it clear all the value used to help in column XFA. So at the end, (the `end with` statment) column XFA return as if never been used, it has no value at all.

Comment: unfortunately the line gives an ERROR mx = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(.Cells) ...note i changed it since the original line also gave an error...   it is looking at the correct values, I added a debug print and the cnt  is the number of sample values on my sheet

Comment: Before `mx = Application.Max(.Cells)`, try to add `.select`. Step run it (debug) and when the yellow past `.select` line, check if (A) it select the correct range in column XFA and (B) all cells in the range is date and time value ... then I think it won't throw an error when the yellow pass ``mx = Application.Max(.Cells)`` you can see a date&time value of mx in local window.